# Is there a way to simulate __typeof__ from GCC extension using standard C++?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, typeof, decltype

Usual answer to this question is that standard C++ decltype is having the same functionality as `__typeof__`.

Which is not true. While decltype can only accept expression as an argument, `__typeof__` can also accept a type name.

However weird this may seem, I have a real use case and I need to port something what I did not write from platform using this extension to platform without the extension. Both, expression and type are passed in by a macro so the rewritten version must accept both.

Simplified sample pseudo code:

```
// from header.h
#define MYMACRO(a)                                            \
                                                              \
    /* long code */                                           \
                                                              \
    using MyTypeA = decltype(some_processing_of #a)           \
    using MyTypeB = __typeof__(a);                            \
                                                              \
    /* long code */                                           \
                                                              \
    using MyType = std::conditional_t<                        \
        is_string_literal_test                                \
        , MyTypeA                                             \
        , MyTypeB >;                                          \
                                                              \
    /* long code */                                           \



// from use_case1.cpp
struct S {};
MYMACRO(S)



// from use_case2.cpp
MYMACRO("some text")



// example of __typeof__ in GCC that compiles
struct S {};
using T1 =  __typeof__(S);
using T2 =  __typeof__("some text");
```

The question is not about the design of surrounding application, it is about simulation of __typeof__ extension within the specification given by implementation in GCC.

Although the use case is a bit narrower than full specification of __typeof__. Instead of all the general expressions it is enough if it works with string literals. Which is not making it easier in case of template and/or SFINAE attempts.

Of course, for my internal purposes I can write MYMACROA for string literals and MYMACROB for types, I would not mind it at all. But it does not have a user experience of the original solution using __typeof__ extension. And that's why I am interested in it.

Comment: _"I have a real use case ..."_ it would be nice if you would [add this as a code example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51272123/edit) into your question.

Comment: C++ has `auto`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ only to satisfy your curiosity :) OP's question is self-contained and doesn't really require MSVC. Sadly, the answer is 'no' :)

Comment: @SergeyA I agree with  πάντα ῥεῖ that it would help to clarify the question if OP could share how they expect to use the code they are asking for.

Comment: @SergeyA I've not been asking for a MCVE, but a _use case_ where _decltype_ doesn't work equally well. Otherwise I'd left a close vote.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As a generic example, `#define pointer(T) typeof(T *)`. In real life C++ program - not sure, should be some ungodly mix of templates, macros and the like.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't understand. If `T` was an expression, wouldn't that fail to compile? E.g. `pointer(1) -> typeof(1 *)` which I can't imagine would compile. So why write `typeof(T *)` rather than just `T *` (or `std::add_pointer_t<T>`)?

Comment: @SergeyA I would prefer to hear from the OP as to what they are doing rather than any guesses, how well informed they may be, from someone else.

Comment: @RichardChambers my argument was (and still is) that `typeof` has different features than `decltype` (in that it accepts types). The question is valid, than, in how one can port program which relied on this feature to the compiler which doesn't have this extension. To THIS question as asked, you do not need to see the original code.

Comment: Hold on. Is `__typeof__` with a type name not just the identity operation!

Comment: @MartinYork it certainly is :)

Comment: Any reason why you can't do `#if HasTypeOfFeature #define __typeof__(T) T`, where HasTypeOfFeature is some check you can do with some builtin for the compiler you use?

Comment: Made a mistake in my comment, but I can't edit anymore. It should be `#if !HasTypeOfFeature`.

Comment: There are several constructs that are valid whether `a` is a type or a string literal - at least, for some types. For example, `const void * foo(a);`, and `a[1]` (assuming that the literal is not empty). Depending on the kind of types you want to support, it may be sufficient.